# addslashes JavaScript equivalent

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping, addslashes

I am looking for a proper version of a JavaScript equivalent of PHP's `addSlashes`.

I have found many versions, but none of them handle `\b`, `\t`, `\n`, `\f` or `\r`.

http://jsfiddle.net/3tEcJ/1/

To be complete, this jsFiddle should alert: `\b\t\n\f\r"\\`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function addslashes(string) {
    return string.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\').
        replace(/\u0008/g, '\\b').
        replace(/\t/g, '\\t').
        replace(/\n/g, '\\n').
        replace(/\f/g, '\\f').
        replace(/\r/g, '\\r').
        replace(/'/g, '\\\'').
        replace(/"/g, '\\"');
}
```

Notice how I've used `\u0008` to replace `\b` with `\\b`. JavaScript's regex syntax doesn't appear to accept `\b`, but it does accept `\u0008`. JavaScript's string literal syntax recognises both `\b` and `\u0008`.

Comment: FWIW `replace(/\b/g, '\\b')` didn't work in my testing on jsfiddle.

Comment: I've just noticed that, and edited my answer to use `\u0008`, which works. Seems like an inconsistency where JavaScript's regex syntax doesn't recognise `\b`.

Comment: `\b` is a boundary condition in regex and needs extra escaping: `\\b` should work.

Answer (score 2):

Or this one from [phpjs.org](http://phpjs.org/functions/addslashes:303)

```
function addslashes(str){
    return  (str + '').replace(/[\\"']/g, '\\$&').replace(/\u0000/g, '\\0');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shorter and surprisingly [more efficient](http://jsperf.com/string-escape-regexp-vs-json-stringify):

```
 function as(str) {
    var a = {};
    a[str] = 1;
    return JSON.stringify(a).slice(1,-3);
  }
```

(`slice(2, -4)` if you don't need quotes around string)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the special character with a backslash \ . Simple and short -

```
let escapeString = unescapeString.replace(/([<>*()?])/g, "\\$1")
```

It will escape the special characters including these too.

> NULL (0x00) --> \0  [This is a zero, not the letter O]
>
> BS  (0x08) --> \b
>
> TAB (0x09) --> \t
>
> LF  (0x0a) --> \n
>
> CR  (0x0d) --> \r
>
> SUB (0x1a) --> \Z
>
> "   (0x22) --> \"
>
> %   (0x25) --> \%
>
> '   (0x27) --> \'
>
> \   (0x5c) --> \
>
> _ (0x5f) --> _